# Do convection currents under the crust affect Earths motion in the solar system?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

Whilst browsing through [this website](http://scienceblogs.com/startswithabang/2011/09/28/why-does-the-earth-have-a-liqu/) I began to wonder whether all of that molten rock underneath the Earth's crust would have a notable effect on how the Earth moves in it's orbit of the Sun.

Considering this stuff is forever shifting and readjusting itself and that it's comprised of different materials it seems understandable to think that there should be some reactions

Comment: Certainly not the *revolution*, because all of them will account for internal forces and won't be able to shift its centre of mass.

Comment: couldn't the centre of mass move if certain heavier materials shifted to one area?

Comment: And what would cause all the heavier materials to shift to one side? Think of it, it can't happen unless there's an equal momentum to the *other* side, which would just cancel it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

Imagine if all the astronauts and cosmonauts inside the ISS started bouncing off the walls, would this impact the trajectory of the ISS. The physics says no. The ISS actually had a [problem like this](http://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/6.IAC-05-C2.4.08), but it does not result in orbital trajectory change. The center of mass of an object in space will move along its path regardless of motion within or about the object itself. Unless an outside force acts on it, or some mass is indefinitely removed. In other words, the only way the core could move the earth out of its orbit, is if it launched lava into space, from some kind of space volcano, with such power the lava leaves the gravitational pull of the earth.

Simple answer
No, the core will most likely never effect the earths orbital path.
Yes, the core could effect earth rotation and/or precession.

Comment: But isn't there any affect on how Earth rotates?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the reminder, never gave a real final answer.

Comment: I think this is true for all practical purposes, but doesn't the distribution of mass also effect orbits? The [J2 effect](https://www.agi.com/resources/academic-resources/astro-primer/primer91.htm), which is caused by earth's oblateness, effects satellites in orbit. I would imagine the reverse would also be true, to a much lesser extent, applied to the sun-earth system.

Comment: Yes, satellite orbits are effected, but mostly by surface changes. That is why we have the GRACE satellite.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_Recovery_and_Climate_Experiment